# Is function name an address to first instruction of that function in c?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

Why is compiler saying that this is not pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double f(){ return 1.2; }
int main(){

    int i=0;
    double d =f()[0]; //f() is not pointer? it should be
    printf("%i\n",d);
}
```

error:

```
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  double d =f()[0];
```

But is I have declared a function pointer, and then used a name of a function, then it *will* become pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int op(int (*op)(int,int), int a, int b){ return op(a,b); }
int add(int a, int b){ return a+b; }

int main(){
    printf("%i\n",op(add, 1, 2)); //here: add() will magically become pointer, different context
}
```

So in first case, I wanted to dereference the function, in hope, the name of the funtion is pointer (and so derefencing is permitted). In second example, the function pointer is declared with pointer, so the function `add` will decay to pointer (compare to `printf("%i\n",op(&add,1,2))`) will also work. So why is problem with the first one?

Comment: Whatever discussion there is about functions a pointers, when you write `f()[0]` you *call* the function and then try to subscript the *result*.

Comment: Why should `f()` return a pointer? You have defined it to return a `double`, not a `double*`.

Comment: @milanHrabos In those terms `f` is the address and `f()` is a call to that address.

Comment: _"f() is not pointer?"_ Correct, `f()` is not a pointer.  _"it should be"_  Why should it be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34463637/1216776

Comment: `&f` is a pointer to f. Using `f`  gives you the value, just  like a variable

Comment: To paraphrase my first comment. You are comparing apples to oranges. An honest comparison would have been `op(a, b)[0]`. Why haven't you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

For a function `f`, or callable in general, `f()` is calling the function and evaluates to the type declared as the functions return type. Functions can decay to pointer to function, similar to arrays, but when you call the function, this doesn't happen:

```
int foo(int,int){ return 1;}

int main() {
    using fptr = int (*)(int,int);
    fptr p = foo;                    // <- function pointer (note: no & needed because it decays to function pointer)
    fptr q = &foo;                   // <- also function pointer
    int x = foo(1,2);                // <- function call
}
```

In your examples:

> ```
> double d =f()[0]; //f() is not pointer? it should be
> ```

No, `f()` is not a pointer. `f` returns a double.

> ```
> printf("%i\n",op(add, 1, 2)); //here: add() will magically become pointer, different context
> ```

No. `add()` will not magically become a pointer. `add` is the function that will automagically decay to function pointer (acutally it isnt that "magic").